# Yii User-friendly url and keep the old get format working

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

I set to the main config the following url rules:

> ```
>     'urlManager'=>array(
>         'urlFormat'=>'path',
>         'showScriptName'=>false,
>         'rules'=>array(
>             '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/list',
>             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
>             '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'<controller>/view',
>             '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
>             '\?r=<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
>         ),
>     ),
> ```

Everything is woking fine, but I also want the previous url format to keep working so I don't have to rewrite lots of urls that I don't care it to be seo-friendly:

```
index.php?r=controller/action&param1=value1
```

But it shows an error now. Is there a way to keep it working?

Comment: You cant do that my friend. it is either 'get' or 'path' urlFormat. You could do rewrite URL in .htaccess or apache to map old urls to new urls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my opinion the best way is to replace all old urls with your IDE regex replace option. But anyway you can do what you want this way:

1. Use following route rule in the urlManager config:

   `'rules' => [
       [
           'class' => 'my\namespace\UrlRule',
           'pattern' => '<controller>/<action>',
           'route' => '<controller>/<action>',
       ],
   ...`
2. Extend yii\web\UrlRule with your my\namespace\UrlRule and rewrite its  'parseRequest' method so that it could use $_GET['r'] parameter value if is set:

```
    namespace my\namespace;

    class UrlRule extends \yii\web\UrlRule
    {
        public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
        {
            if ($pathInfo = \Yii::$app->request->get('r')) {
                \Yii::$app->request->setPathInfo($pathInfo);
            }
            return parent::parseRequest($manager, $request);
        }
    }
```

You may also extend yii\web\Request instead so that it's 'getPathInfo' method could use $_GET['r'] parameter if set.

Comment: Can you explain what is $pathInfo or complete the example? It doesn't seem to exist and I can't find anywhere else an example of custom urlrule to allow get format urls.

Comment: The example is fully completed and working except of UrlRule namespace. Maybe it's not the best practice but I DEFINE $pathInfo in the if() statement. It is the same like: $pathInfo = \Yii::$app->request->get('r'); if ($pathInfo) end so on.